# Async Series Giving UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous

I have a function that is using async series method. This is because I need that function1 must execute before function2, which subsequently must execute before function 3.

```
async.series([
function1 (function(err, customers) { stufftodo1; }),
function2 (function(err, customers) { stufftodo2; }),
function3 (function(err, customers) { stufftodo3; })
]);
```

I get this error within an express node.js app, which I am unsure as to how to handle:

```
(node:22888) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: expected a function
    at wrapAsync (/home/ubuntu/concept/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:198:50)
    at /home/ubuntu/concept/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:2952:13
    at replenish (/home/ubuntu/concept/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:444:21)
    at /home/ubuntu/concept/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:449:13
    at eachOfLimit$1 (/home/ubuntu/concept/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:475:34)
    at awaitable(eachOfLimit$1) (/home/ubuntu/concept/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:208:32)
    at eachOfSeries (/home/ubuntu/concept/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:662:16)
    at awaitable(eachOfSeries) (/home/ubuntu/concept/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:208:32)
    at /home/ubuntu/concept/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:2951:9
    at /home/ubuntu/concept/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:216:25
(node:22888) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you lost the function to handle error and result.

```
async.series([function1, function2], function(error, results) {});
```

Do you use the npm package:async?

Comment: Yes I am using the npm package async. I added what you said but now I get a "Error: expected a function.  at awaitable() (/home/ubuntu/concept/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:208:32" error message. In addition, I can tell that it is not running in series because the webpage is not displaying the data from the API in time before it can retrieve it. I have to refresh the page for a second time until the data comes in.